# Declaration is incompatible with prototype

Tags: c++, function, prototype

I'm confused at to why I'm getting this error. The title's error is happening with the prototype in Globals.h:

```
void NPCTalk(std::string const& speaker,std::vector<std::string> const& text)
```

and the function in Functions.cpp:

```
void NPCTalk(string const& speaker,std::vector<std::string> const& text){
    vector<string>::const_iterator it;
    for (it=text.begin();it!=text.end();it++){
        cout << speaker << ": " << *it << endl << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Compile eror? Do you have using namespace std; in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon at the end of the prototype. Your signatures are a match which suggests to me that you may well have forgotten the namespace in question.